# write image tags inside c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code, and I would like to add an image from C# but I am unable to.

**defualt.aspx**

```
<li runat="server" id="searchbox">
   </li>
```

**code behind**

```
String name =jack;
String terms = Request["search"];
searchbox.InnerText = "<img src"users/'"+name+"'.png"/>"+ terms; //name and terms is a varible which is storing information from database
```

I am a beginner in ASP.NET, so I don't know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `InnerHtml` instead of InnerText.
Also notice that you're missing an `=` after `src`

```
searchbox.InnerHtml = "<img src=\"users/" + name + ".png\"/>"+ terms;
```